# How to stop internal links from turning to #REF?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a tab (Tab A) in my workbook that has links to another tab (Tab B and Tab C) that VBA inserts with `Application.GetOpenFilename`. When I run the macro I get `#REF!` in Tab A for the formulas on that tab (the formulas reference the inserted tabs ie Tab B and Tab C). How can I prevent this from happening and to keep the formulas on Tab A intact?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Data_Tab()
    '
    ' Data Tab Macro
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("CC_DMSR").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "CC_DMSR"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim PasteStart As Range

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set PasteStart = [CC_DMSR!A1]

    Sheets("CC_DMSR").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    MsgBox "Please select the CC DMSR File"
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
    FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlsx (*.xlsx),")

    If FileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

        For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
            With Sheet.UsedRange
                .Copy PasteStart
                Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        Next Sheet

    End If

    wb2.Close

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Submitted_DMSR").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Submitted_DMSR"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set PasteStart = [Submitted_DMSR!A1]

    Sheets("Submitted_DMSR").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    MsgBox "Please select the Submitted DMSR File"
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a Report to Parse", _
    FileFilter:="Report Files *.xlsx (*.xlsx),")

    If FileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

        For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
            With Sheet.UsedRange
                .Copy PasteStart
                Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        Next Sheet

    End If

    wb2.Close

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = _
        xlMissingItemsNone
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = _
        xlMissingItemsNone
    With Sheets("Comparison").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("TASK/TB")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    With Sheets("Comparison").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("TASK/TB")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With


    Dim bottomrow As Long

    Sheets("Comparison").Select
    bottomrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("D4:J4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D4:J" & bottomrow), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Call sourceSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Would be helpful to spell out which sheets are which.  How are A, B and C related to your posted code?

Comment: @Tim Williams, this question is like the one he ask on 29 Nov, too broad and not specific enough, or am i wrong?

Comment: Tab A is Comparison Tab B is Submitted_DMSR and Tab C is CC_DMSR

Comment: @GMalc59 Not sure how this is too broad. Did you even read the post?

Comment: You could try turning off calculations and/or replacing the data instead of deleting the sheets.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the sheet content instead of deleting the sheet and adding a new one with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if just opening wb2 is introducing the REF errors or the insertion of the sheets.

E.g.
If you open workbook1, which has a formula which contains a reference to workbook2, and workbook2 is then opened in Protected Mode (per default settings), Excel will introduce REF errors in any cells with references to workbook2 (due to Protected mode).

If the above is your problem, then one way might be to add wb2 as trusted document or location, or Excel>File>Options>And turn off protected mode (inadvisable).

Irrespective of the above, other solution is you using:

1. Range.Find and loop through all cells with references to the
   sheet(s)    that will be inserted

   2. Temporarily replace the first '=' with ' =' in these cells, which should turn the formula into a string value.
   3. You then insert the sheets you want (string values can't experience REF errors)
   4. Then replace ' =' with '=' to convert string back to Excel formula.

You could set a range object in step 1 that could then be reused in step 2 and 3.